# ¿Como implementar alerta sweetalert de eliminacion con javascript y ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Quiero implementar alerta de confirmación para hacer una eliminación. Antes tenia una alerta simple y quiero actualizarla poniendo una alerta con sweetalert. Ya intente varias formas de implementar pero no logo llegar al objetivo. Seria de gran ayuda que me ayuden por favor. Muchas gracias.

Así tenia antes mi alerta.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){  
       var user_id = $(this).attr("id");  
       if(confirm("Deseas eliminar?"))  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Productos/delete_single_user",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{user_id:user_id},  
                 success:function(data)  
                 {  
                      alert(data);  
                      dataTable.ajax.reload();  
                 }  
            });  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            return false;       
       }
  });
```

Y estoy intentando de diferente forma pero no me queda.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){  
           var user_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(swal({
                          title: 'Deseas eliminar?',
                          icon: 'warning',
                          showCancelButton: true,
                          confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                          cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                          confirmButtonText: 'si,'
                        }))  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>Productos/delete_single_user",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{user_id:user_id},  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          alert(data);  
                          dataTable.ajax.reload();  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                return false;       
           }  
      });
```

Comment: que version de sweetalert estas usando?

Comment: La versión es sweetalert2

Comment: ya pero que versión 7, 8 o 9?

Comment: Es versión 8 amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como pone en los [ejemplos](https://sweetalert2.github.io/v8.html#examples) tienes que usar el método `Swal.fire` para mostrar el alert y esto devuelve una promesa, por lo tanto, tienes que añadir un callback con `then` ahí tienes que validar si el usuario ha clicado `si` o `no`.

Sweetalert se encarga de devolverte un objeto con la respuesta del usuario, en este caso, lo he llamado `result` pero puedes llamarlo como quieras.

En función de eso haces la llamada ajax.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  var user_id = $(this).attr("id");
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Deseas eliminar?',
    icon: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'si,'
  }).then(result => {
    if (result.value) {
      borrarProducto(user_id);
    }
  });
});


function borrarProducto(user_id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Productos/delete_single_user",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      dataTable.ajax.reload();
    }
  });
}
```

Si no quieres usar `then` puedes [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me funciono correctamente.Entiendo lo que me dices... nuevamente gracias